# How to run a Python program with specified number of cores and track it's memory and execution time?

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I am looking to vary the number of cores my Python program uses, then measure the corresponding memory usage and execution time the program consumes when using the specified number of cores. Essentially, I am just wanting to see what number of cores vs memory usage vs execution time is optimal for my program.

My idea so far is to use Python's multiprocessing module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to set the number of cores that my process is using psutil package (https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).

For example:

```
def process():
    # the process I want to measure 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_dict = {'num_cores': [], 'memory': [], 'execution_time': []}
    num_cores = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]

    for cores in num_cores:
        with Pool(cores) as p:
            start_time = time.time()
            p.map(process)
            mem = int(int(psutil.virtual_memory().total) / 1024 / 1024)
            end_time = time.time()
            total_time = end_time - start_time

            df_dict['num_cores'].append(cores)
            df_dict['memory'].append(mem)
            df_dict['execution_time'].append(total_time)
```

But this doesn't work as I am not including an iterable in `p.map(process)`. I am also not sure if this is the correct way to measure the memory usage.

How would I go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: "But this doesn't work as I am not including an iterable in p.map(process)" ... ok? It seems like you are just asking how to use `multiprocessing`. Have you done any research? For starters, the official documentation? How about googling for specific questions on Stack Overflow (there are many)

Comment: It's very important to understand, the CPython runtime has a global interpreter lock (GIL), a CPython process will only ever use a single CPU core.

Comment: You'll want to trace memory and execution time separately. Python's `tracemalloc` library adds a fairly measurable latency, and will slow down perf.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, ...the OP is specifying multiprocessing, hence, forking multiple processes each with its own GIL.

Comment: @sigmabean, ...it's unclear here if you're asking how to tell multiprocessing how large of a pool to spawn, or how to configure the OS to constrain your Python interpreter _above and beyond_ multiprocessing's configuration. Those are very different questions.

Comment: there are missing imports and undefined variables in the example code. it would be helpful if a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) was provided.